# Can't increase the text size of listarray for button or rounded them

Tags: android, android-layout, button, arraylist, text-size

I have a `List` of buttons.

I want to increase the `sizetext` of buttons and round them (make them have round-corners). I tried many ways, but I can't get it fixed.

```
private List<Button> buttons;

private static final int[] BUTTON_IDS = {
    R.id.button1,
    R.id.button2,
    R.id.button3,
    R.id.button4,
    R.id.button5,
    R.id.button6,
    R.id.button7,
    R.id.button8,
    R.id.button9,
    R.id.button10,
    R.id.button11,
    R.id.button12,
    R.id.button13,
    R.id.button14,
    R.id.button15,
    R.id.button16
};
```

and in the `onCreate` method, I call this function to initialize the `List`

```
public void initialbutton() {
    buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
    for (int id : BUTTON_IDS) {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(id);
        button.setTypeface(typeFace);
        button.setTextSize(30);// this part didnt work
        buttons.add(button);
    }
}
```

and this is one XML layout, I define buttons from the `List` this way

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:textSize="40sp"
/>
```

Comment: Can u post  your code

Comment: i edit the question with the code@AnilDS

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

for rounded drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/color_rounded_btn"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/color_rounded_btn"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I used that but didn't work '<Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button16"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            />' @jaffar

Comment: you are trying to inflate buttons through programatically?

Comment: if that possible @jaffar